# Maxima and minima of function of two variables.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If $$f(x,y)=x^{2}+y^{3}+\frac{768}{x+y}$$
then find the points where it attains its extrema.

For this I have done the following:
$$f_x=2x-\frac{768}{(x+y)^{2}}$$
$$f_y=3y^{2}-\frac{768}{(x+y)^{2}}$$
Putting $f_x=0$ and $f_y=0$,
$$2x=\frac{768}{(x+y)^{2}}$$
$$3y^{2}=\frac{768}{(x+y)^{2}}$$

$$\implies\frac{2x}{3y^{2}}=1$$

$$\implies\frac{x}{y^{2}}=\frac{6}{4}$$

So, $x=6, y=2$ is a stationary point.

But in the book, it is given that $(5.99,-2.45)$ is another stationary point which satisfies the parabola $2x=3y^{2}$. But I can not find the way to proceed. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

When calculating the stationary points you correctly ended up with
$$
f_x = 0 = 2x - \frac{768}{(x+y)^2}\quad\text{and}\quad
f_y = 0 = 3y^2 - \frac{768}{(x+y)^2}
$$
which implies $2x = 3y^2$ **and** $2x = 768/(x+y)^2$.  Substitute the first equation in the second to obtain,
$$
3y^2 = 768/\big(\tfrac{3}{2}y^2+y\big)^2
$$
which with rearrangement becomes,
$$
9y^6+12y^5+4y^4-1024 = 0.
$$
You need then to plot the graph of this $6$th order polynomial to see there are just two real roots.  One is when $y=2$, as posted, and numerical methods, for example Newton-Raphson, or even trial and error, will show the second root is at $y \approx -2.4474$.

Final comment:  when looking for the absolute maximum or minimum of the function $f(x,y)$ you need to say what is the domain for $x, y$.  If both are unconstrained, just by inspection you can see $f(x,y)$ approaches $+\infty$ by making $x$ large and $y=0$, $-\infty$ by making $y$ large and negative, $x=0$ and for $x=-y$ the function is undefined.  Thus there is no absolute maximum or minimum, and your calculation is only showing local turning points, which may be local extrema or simply saddles.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from @WA Don's answer, wa have
$$9y^6+12y^5+4y^4-1024=(y-2) \left(3 y^2+8 y+16\right) \left(3 y^3+2 y^2+32\right)$$
$(3 y^2+8 y+16)$ does not show any real root nad we are left with the solutions of
$$3 y^3+2 y^2+32=0$$ whidh has only one real root since $\Delta=-249856$.

Using the hyperbolic method, the real root is given by
$$y=-\frac{2}{9} \left(1+2 \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh ^{-1}(487)\right)\right)\approx -2.44743$$ and, from $2x=3y^2$,
$$x=\frac{2}{27} \left(1+2 \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh ^{-1}(487)\right)\right)^2\approx 8.98489$$

All of this leads to a minimum value $\approx 183.545$.